# How Spring knows bean to inject with @Bean and method call

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm trying some stuff with Spring Framework and I would like to know how Spring can inject singleton dependency with method call when using java configuration?

Example :

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public BlogRepository blogRepository() {
        return new BlogRepositoryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public BlogService blogService() {
        return new BlogServiceImpl(blogRepository());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorService authorService() {
        return new AuthorServiceImpl(blogRepository());
    }
}
```

I know that this class is also a bean and it is proxied by Spring but, how can Spring always get the existing `BlogRepository` singleton since I call `blogRepository()` from within the class and so proxy can't handle the call?

Answer (score 2):

When you annotate class with `@Configuration`, methods annotated with `@Bean` are proxy wrapped by `CGLIB`.

If it’s the first call of this method, then the original method’s body will be executed and the resulting object will be stored in the `Spring` context. All subsequent calls just return the bean retrieved from the context.

Comment: Yes, but when Spring calls `blogService()`, for the first time, the call is passed to `super.blogService()` to instanciate the bean and then, `blogRepository()` is called from the super class, so the proxy can't do the check.

Comment: If you debug the application, you will notice that your class `AppConfiguration` was dynamically generated at runtime by Spring using CGLIB. It will most likely have a name similar to `AppConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$...`. Once a `blogRepository()` method is called, what is really invoked is `intercept(..)` method of `ConfigurationClassEnhancer`. It uses `AbstractBeanFactory` to instantiate beans. If such a bean exists, it is returned from context. Otherwise, new bean is created and stored in the context.

Comment: I'll test that. I didn't mind to try debug on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think proxy cannot handle the call?

Spring *could* generate a proxy similar to this subclass:

```
class AppConfigurationProxy extends AppConfiguration {
    private BlogRepository blogRepository;

    @Override
    public BlogRepository blogRepository() {
        if (blogRepository == null)
            blogRepository = super.blogRepository();
        return blogRepository;
    }

    // same for the other two @Bean methods
}
```

Now, no matter how many times a method inside `AppConfiguration` calls it's own `blogRepository()` method, it will always get the same object.

---

**UPDATE:** Proof that above would work.

*Simple Bean interfaces*

```java
public interface BlogRepository {
}

public interface BlogService {
}

public interface AuthorService {
}
```

*Simple Bean classes*

They don't have any actual logic, just a `toString()` implementation that shows the "identity" of the object, similar to the default `toString()` implementation in class `Object`.

```java
public class BlogRepositoryImpl implements BlogRepository {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BlogRepositoryImpl@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
}

public class BlogServiceImpl implements BlogService {
    private BlogRepository blogRepository;
    public BlogServiceImpl(BlogRepository blogRepository) {
        this.blogRepository = blogRepository;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BlogServiceImpl@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode()) + "[blogRepository=" + this.blogRepository + "]";
    }
}

public class AuthorServiceImpl implements AuthorService {
    private BlogRepository blogRepository;
    public AuthorServiceImpl(BlogRepository blogRepository) {
        this.blogRepository = blogRepository;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AuthorServiceImpl@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode()) + "[blogRepository=" + this.blogRepository + "]";
    }
}
```

*Configuration class*

As defined in the question.

```java
public class AppConfiguration {
    public BlogRepository blogRepository() {
        return new BlogRepositoryImpl();
    }
    public BlogService blogService() {
        return new BlogServiceImpl(blogRepository());
    }
    public AuthorService authorService() {
        return new AuthorServiceImpl(blogRepository());
    }
}
```

*Proxy class as String could have implemented it*

Same as at top of the answer, just completed with all the methods.

```java
public class AppConfigurationProxy extends AppConfiguration {
    private BlogRepository blogRepository;
    private BlogService blogService;
    private AuthorService authorService;
    @Override
    public BlogRepository blogRepository() {
        if (this.blogRepository == null)
            this.blogRepository = super.blogRepository();
        return this.blogRepository;
    }
    @Override
    public BlogService blogService() {
        if (this.blogService == null)
            this.blogService = super.blogService();
        return this.blogService;
    }
    @Override
    public AuthorService authorService() {
        if (this.authorService == null)
            this.authorService = super.authorService();
        return this.authorService;
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Show result without proxy
        AppConfiguration config = new AppConfiguration();
        System.out.println(config.blogRepository());
        System.out.println(config.blogService());
        System.out.println(config.authorService());

        // Show how only one BlogRepository is craeted when proxy is used
        config = new AppConfigurationProxy();
        System.out.println(config.blogRepository());
        System.out.println(config.blogService());
        System.out.println(config.authorService());
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
BlogRepositoryImpl@1e81f4dc
BlogServiceImpl@7960847b[blogRepository=BlogRepositoryImpl@6a6824be]
AuthorServiceImpl@2c13da15[blogRepository=BlogRepositoryImpl@77556fd]

BlogRepositoryImpl@9e89d68
BlogServiceImpl@3b192d32[blogRepository=BlogRepositoryImpl@9e89d68]
AuthorServiceImpl@16f65612[blogRepository=BlogRepositoryImpl@9e89d68]
```

As can be seen, the first part, which didn't use the proxy, ends up with 3 different instances of `BlogRepositoryImpl`.

With the use of the Proxy, only one instance of `BlogRepositoryImpl` is created, and shared even though `blogService()` calls `blogRepository()` "directly".

Comment: Yes, but when Spring calls `blogService()`, for the first time, the call is passed to `super.blogService()` to instanciate the bean and then, `blogRepository()` is called from the super class, so the proxy can't do the check.

Comment: @FaridM And when `AppConfiguration.blogService()` calls `blogRepository()`, it is the `AppConfigurationProxy.blogRepository()` method that is called, because that it how method overrides work!!! It's inheritance!!! It's dynamic dispatch!!!

Comment: How `AppConfiguration` knows there is a proxy? There is no reference of the proxy inside `AppConfiguration`. So how `blogRepository()` inside `AppConfiguration.blogService()` can call the proxy?

Comment: Class `AppConfiguration` doesn't. The `this` reference variable refers to the proxy subclass of `AppConfiguration`. Exactly like when you have classes `Animal` and `Dog`, and the created object instance is a `Dog`, then a method in `Animal` that calls another method which happens to be overridden by class `Dog` will call the `Dog` version of the method. It's standard Java, and if you don't understand inheritance and method overriding, then take a step back and go back to your Java for Beginners Guide and (re)read it.

Comment: @FaridM *"From where the this come from?"* `this` **always** refers to the actual instance of the object that was created. --- Using `super.method(...)` means the compile *resolves* the method by only looking at methods declared in the superclass. The `this` value in that method call it the same `this` value as the current method, i.e. it still refers to the instance of the proxy subclass.